# htaccess URL rewrite to set none SEO url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

I need to send request to a none seo url in opencart.

Ex : 
`https://xxxxxxx.yyy.zz/index.php?search=apple`   <-- 1st Url

This will not load the Search page
But the noe SEO url will load the search page like below

```
https://xxxxxxx.yyy.zz/index.php?route=product/search&search=apple
```

<-- 2nd Url

How to redirect 1st Url to 2nd Url ?

Comment: So `route=product/search` is a static value or it can change for other URLs?

Comment: Did you enable seo urls and what is your OC version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it via php and inside OpenCart framework, you can do it this way:

In `catalog\controller\common\header.php`

**Find:**

```
public function index() {
```

**Add after it:**

```
// Get url parameters
$get = $this->request->get;

// Get current route
$route = isset($get['route']) ? $get['route'] : '';

// If the Search parameter is available in the url, but the current page is not the search page
if(isset($get['search']) && $route != 'product/search'){
    // Redirect user to the search page with search keyword
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('product/search', 'search=' . $this->request->get['search'], true));
}
```